# Qt3D/C++: How to stop rendering while updating the Scenegraph

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d

I've got a C++/QWidgets application with 2 Qt3DWindow embedded. The 3D windows can be hidden (i.e. the user switches to another view), while work is done in other parts of the application. Whenever the user switches back to the view with the embedded Qt3DWindow there are a lot of changes to be made to the scenegraph.

Rendering is set to *OnDemand*, but whenever the view is switched back to the 3D windows there is a big lag, up to several seconds. Profiling the application has shown that a lot of work is done for rendering at that point because the scenegraph is changing (most time is spent in the material classes).

My working theory is, that each change to the scenegraph (i.e. removing an entity, adding a new one) causes a separate render update, which leads to the lag due to the amount of separate changes.

So my question is:

**Is there a way to stop all render updates until the scenegraph has been updated/modified completely?**

I'm thinking of something similar to the beginResetModel() and endResetModel() methods in QAbstractItemModel.

Comment: Not sure if this will work but you could try to disable the scene root `QEntity`. I'm not sure how well the Qt people implemented skipping this node in this case since the docs state somewhere that the node might be considered by some aspects anyway but maybe this allows you to first modify the scene graph and then render the scene in one go.

Comment: After some profiling the problem seems to be that there are lots of worker threads (usually between 12 and 14) in the renderer that wait for other worker threads to be done. Why it takes up to 10 seconds on an octacore Ryzen7 5000 with 40 GBytes of RAM for all threads to finish for a simple scene with some lights and 7 low poly geometries is beyond me...